# Erro de conexão no mariadb

Tags: php, mysql, linux, mariadb

Hoje instalei o `lamp` no meu `manjaro` e estava tudo funcionando normalmente, até que fui testar o php com mysql e digitei o código:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','data');
```

Percebo que, após isso, todo o resto do código é descartado, como se o código acabasse ali, mesmo o código html digitado após isso é descartado, não sei o que fazer

Answer (score 1):

A função [**mysqli_query**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php) serve para você executar comando do SQL quando ele já está conectado. Por exemplo:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users");
```

Para conectar ao banco de dados é necessário utilizar a função `mysqli_connect` ou o construtor `new mysqli()`. Ex:

**Orientação a Objeto**

```
$db = new MySQLi("localhost", "usuário-db", "senha-db", "database", "porta-do-mariadb")

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Error: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```

**Utilizando método estático**

```
$db = MySQLi::connect("localhost", "usuário-db", "senha-db", "database", "porta-do-mariadb")

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Error: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```

**Utilizando programação procedural**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuário-db", "senha-db", "database", "porta-do-mariadb")

if (!$db) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

> Caso a porta de sua conexão seja a padrão (3306), não precisa colocar. Ela já está setada no `php.ini`

---

**Configurando os dados através do `php.ini`**

Caso você opte por configurar os dados através do `php.ini`, não é necessário passar nenhum parâmetros. Isso forçará o `PHP` a utilizar as configurações setadas no arquivo supracitado.

Nesse caso você pode abrir seu `php.ini` e adicionar as seguintes linhas:

```
[mysqli]
mysqli.default_host = 127.0.0.1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_user = "usuário-do-db"
mysqli.default_pw = "senha-do-db"
```

Utilizando dessa forma você poderá fazer a conexão da seguinte maneira:

```
/* Orientado a Objeto */
$db = new MySQLi();
$db->select_db("nome-do-db");

/* Procedural */
$db = mysqli_connect();
mysqli_select_db($db, "nome-do-db");
```

Após um dos métodos listados acima, você poderá utilizar a função [**mysqli_query**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php).

Comment: aaah eu errei na hora de fazer a pergunta, tinha usado mysqli_connect mesmo

Comment: @GabrielLothric Tente fazer como mencionei em *"Utilizando programação procedural"*

Comment: Adicione a condição e o die para verificar o erro.

Comment: Eu tentei todos os metodos, nenhum deu certo, e o die não aparece

Comment: @GabrielLothric edite sua pergunta e adicione como você está executando as `queries`.